# Boolean model attributes as automatic methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working through http://railstutorial.org (currently working on section 10.4.2 - destroying users).

My User model has a boolean `admin` attribute, and in the Users controller there is some simple code making use of this attribute:

```
def admin_user
  redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
end
```

The RSpec test:

```
describe "as a non-signed-in user" do
  it "should deny access" do
    delete :destroy, :id => @user
    response.should redirect_to(signin_path)
  end
end
```

And the error this test produces:

> NoMethodError in 'UsersController DELETE 'destroy' as a non-signed-in user should deny access'
>   undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass

What is nil:NilClass? Why am I getting this?

***edit*:** j., this might help:

```
  def sign_in(user)
    user.remember_me!
    cookies[:remember_token] = { :value => user.remember_token,
                                :expires => 20.years.from_now.utc }
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
  end
```

Comment: Looks like `current_user` is nil.

Comment: Daniel, same error after changing it to @current_user

Comment: Check the `current_user` method. It's returning `nil`. Could you post this method?

Comment: j., you're right, `current_user` is nil. It is initialized at `sign_in`, which doesn't occur for this test, since I'm testing a user who hasn't signed in. I have `before_filter :admin_user, :only => :destroy` in my User controller code, which triggers admin_user when destroy is called.

Comment: Right. So Larry K's answer is the way to go. You have to test if `current_user` exists using `unless current_user && current_user.admin?` :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news! Your rspec test found a bug!

Your controller method

```
def admin_user
  redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
end
```

is being called directly or indirectly by your controller's delete action.

And admin_user is being called when current_user is nil. So the admin_user method is failing with the error

```
undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass
```

fix: depends on how admin_user is being called and used. Is it in a filter?

Could be changed to either of

```
def admin_user
  redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user && current_user.admin?
end

# or
def admin_user
  redirect_to(root_path) if current_user && !current_user.admin?
end
```

depending on the situation....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your current_user object is nil and it should be nil.

As you are not signed in then surely your current _user is nil and then you are trying to get
nil.admin? so that's why it give No method error.

Probabily you should rewrite your method something like

```
def admin_user
  redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user || current_user.admin?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you complete section [9.3.4 Current User](http://railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec:current_user) of the tutorial? This creates a `current_user` variable within the `SessionsController` via the inclusion of the `SessionsHelper` module.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem, and I found that the underlying problem was that I'd failed to add `:destroy` to the `before_filter :authenticate` in app/controllers/users_controller.rb, as below (from [listing 10.41](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#code%3aadmin_destroy_before_filter):

`before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]`